# total array sum using pdo

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to get total price from cart table. The product_price in other table which is product. I'm only getting the latest price not the total price. Thanks

```
//  function total_price (){

$total = 0;

global $db;
$ip = getIp();

    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * from cart WHERE ip_add='$ip'");

    $no=$sql->rowCount();   // number of rows affected by the last SQL statement  
    if ($no == 0){
        echo "";


    } else {
        foreach($sql as $row)

            $product_id = $row["p_id"];
            $sql = $db->query("SELECT product_price from product WHERE product_id='$product_id'");
            $no=$sql->rowCount();   // number of rows affected by the last SQL statement  
            if ($no == 0){
            echo "";
            }
            else
            {
            foreach($sql as $row)
            $product_price = array($row["product_price"]);

            $values = array_sum($product_price );
            $total += $values;

            }
    }

    echo "RM" . $total;

        }
```

Comment: if all you need is a sum of the cart items prices, you could do it with a single query

Comment: `fetch` only pulls one row. Loop it. Also an `ip` is not unique to a user. You also are open to SQL injections, parameterize.

Answer (score 1):

if I'm reading the structure right this one query should be all you need:

```
select sum(product_price) from product 
inner join cart on product.product_id=cart.product_id
```

Comment: i change to this code but there is no output for total price             function total_price() {
  global $db;
  $ip = getIp();

  $query = $db->prepare('
    SELECT SUM(p.product_price * c.quantity) AS total FROM cart AS c
JOIN product AS p ON p.product_id = c.p_id
WHERE c.ip_add = :ip
  ');
  $query->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
  $query->execute();

  $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if($row) {
    $total = (float) $row['total'];
  } else {
    $total = 0;
  }

  return $total;
}